# Element undefined in jQuery each iteration

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to iterate over a collection of jQuery elements as follows:

```
var l = $(".ace_line").length;
$(".ace_line").each($(function(index,element) {
    console.log("Element = " + element);
    console.log(index + ": " + element.text());
}));
```

When I examine `l` its value is 39 so I know the collection is not null.
However `element` is undefined when I loop through the collection.

What am I doing wrong?

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A couple of problems there:

1. You're wrapping your callback in `$()`, which makes jQuery think you're using the shorthand version of `$(document).ready(function...)`. Since the DOM is ready, it calls that function (once) passing it the `jQuery` instance as the first argument and no second argument at all.
2. You're *not* using `$()` around `element`. `element` will just be a DOM element, not a jQuery instance, so to call `text` on it, you need to wrap it first.

So:

```
var l = $(".ace_line").length;
$(".ace_line").each(function(index,element) {
// No $( here ------^
    var $el = $(element);                     // <=== Do wrap `element`
    console.log("Element = " + $el);
    console.log(index + ": " + $el.text());   // <=== Use $el
}); // <== Removed a ) here
```

Note that the more normal thing to do would be to use `this`:

```
var l = $(".ace_line").length;
$(".ace_line").each(function(index) {
    var $el = $(this);                        // <===
    console.log("Element = " + $el);
    console.log(index + ": " + $el.text());   // <===
});
```

Comment: Thank you to everyone for all your help. T.J.Crowder's answer was very well-explained and has helped me solve my issue so I'm accepting this one.

Answer (score 2):

Remove the `$(` from within the each function, like so:

```
var l = $(".ace_line").length;
$(".ace_line").each(function(index,element) {
    console.log("Element = " + element);
    console.log(index + ": " + $(element).text());
});
```

Additionally, your `element` will be a HTML DOM element, not a jQuery item, so to get `.text()` you would need `$(element).text()`

Answer (score 0):

- you are using wrong syntax `$(function(){})`
- caching variables makes your script is faster
- `for` is faster than `each()`
- by using `for` you do not have to wrap your element with `$()` again

**jQuery**

```
var lines = $(".ace_line"); //caching the element
var l = lines.length; //getting length for loop without selecting element again
for (var j = 0; j < l; j++){ //for loop where j is your index
    console.log(lines.eq(j)); //getting the element by using jQuery's eq()
    console.log(lines.eq(j).text()); //use any jQuery function on the element
}
```

Comment: Using `eq` in this way, regardless of caching, will not improve performance any. In addition, you haven't renamed your `i` variable to `j`. http://jsperf.com/for-vs-jquery-each-and-text